# How to find the list of columns which are all having null or NA values in spark scala Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark

How to find the list of columns name which are all having null or NA values in spark scala Dataframe?

I have tried with bellow code,I did not get expected results.

```
val cond = df8.columns.map(x => col(x).isNull || col(x) === "NA")

val df = Seq((Some(1.0), Some("NA"), null).toDF("A", "B", "C")
```

output List should contain B and C columns

Expected Results:`List[B,C]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically filter each column and count the number of null as below (add more logic on a filter for checking nulls as you want )

```
df.columns.map(c => (c, df.filter(col(c).isNotNull && !col(c).isNaN).count()))
    .filter(_._2 < 1)
    .map(_._1)
```

Output:

```
List[B,C]
```

Comment: Note that the code above will choke on date columns (`.isNaN` will not accept the datatype).

Answer (score 0):

You can get array of columns and then loop and collect each column values as a set and check if set contains null.

df.columns()   -- will give array of columns

df.select("column_name").collect.map(_(0)).toSet.contains(null)   -- will give true if complete column is null.