# PySpark - how to replace null array in JSON file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have JSON files with null arrays (`array (nullable = true)` and `element: (containsNull = true)`) that I'd like to convert to parquet files. These null fields are dropped automatically, while all other columns are converted as expected. Is there a way to replace the null arrays with something else (eg `["-"]`)?
I'm running my code in AWS Glue, but the replacement would take place using pure PySpark and dataframes.

The data type must still be an array in the parquet file (just not with null values).

json:

```
{
 "a":[],
 "b":[1,2],
 "c": "a string"
}
```

Expected output:

```
   a  |   b   |     c
["-"] | [1,2] | "a string"
```

Current script:

```
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields", "false")

job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

inputDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type="s3",
                                                        connection_options:{
                                                             "s3://my-bucket", 
                                                             "recurse":True
                                                           }, 
                                                        format="json")
df = inputDF.toDF()
# replace empty arrays here
dynamic = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "dynamic")

output = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=dynamic,
                                                      connection_type="s3",
                                                      connection_options={
                                                           "path":"s3://my-bucket"
                                                           },
                                                      format="parquet"
                                                      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which spark version you are using, I have checked with spark 3.1.2 and 2.4.5 where empty array fields are not getting ignored.

You can use below line to get desired result,

```
df.withColumn('a', when(size('a')== 0, array(lit('-'))).otherwise(col('a'))).show()

+---+------+--------+
|  a|     b|       c|
+---+------+--------+
|[-]|[1, 2]|a string|
+---+------+--------+
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! Is there a way of identifying all columns (struct, array or string) which are NullFields?

Comment: Do you need to get the columns which has all nulls and one or more?

Comment: Only columns which are all null.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044484/how-to-find-the-list-of-columns-which-are-all-having-null-or-na-values-in-spark